# Is "bolt" only used if running away from someone/something?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

**BOLT**

Verb

(of a horse or other animal) run away suddenly, typically from fear.
"the horses shied and bolted"

(of a person) move or run away suddenly in an attempt to escape.
"they bolted down the stairs"

**Question:**

Will it sound odd to use "bolt" in contexts where someone is not running away from someone in fear or could it easily be used if eg. someone run after someone to chase them?

Comment: You haven't understood the scope of "to bolt" correctly. It basically means ***to move suddenly*** - not necessarily *escaping in fear*. A child could bolt out of the front door and run to an ice-cream van outside, for example (in *eager anticipation*, rather than fear). It's also worth being aware of the horticulture "subsense" *to ‘run to seed’ prematurely*. Not to mention *bolting one's food* (eating very quickly).

Comment: [Lexico:](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bolt) **bolt** (of a horse or other animal) run away suddenly, typically from fear. Example: *‘the horses shied and bolted’*